# Nexus won't index Central: Prefix file size exceeds maximum allowed size

Tags: nexus

My Nexus 2.13.0-01 instance which I installed fresh won't index Central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/). The Routing tab shows message

> Remote strategy prefix-file on M2Repository(id=central) detected
>   invalid input, results discarded: Prefix file size exceeds maximum
>   allowed size (100000), refusing to load it.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, and it was fixed a while ago:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10233

Upgrading will resolve this.